# I'm not sure, are there 46 or 92 DNA strands in each somatic cell. Whatever, how many, then these strands join together to make a 6 or 7 ft long DNA?

Tags: genetics

When a cell is not divided it has DNA in chromatin form. Usually it is written in books that DNA is 6 ft long. In each cell there are 46 chromosomes, so there are 46 or 92 DNA strands. When a cell is not divided, do all these strands join together to make a 6 ft long DNA strand?

Comment: no its total length, each chromosome is a separate strand

Answer (score 2):

This is a science website. Please, keep it clean, keep it metric! 6.5 feet ≈ 200 cm.

The exact length is subject to quite a bit of variation from estimates to estimates, at least according to [hypertext.com](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1998/StevenChen.shtml) (non-peer reviewed). All estimates are in between 1.5 meters and 3 meters. Hypertext.com cite "Cell." The World Book Encyclopedia. Chicago: Field Enterprises, 1996

> On the average, a single human chromosome consists of DNA molecule that is about 2 inches [(~5 cm)] long.

They deduce from it a total length of 230 cm which mean that they computed 5 * 23 * 2 = 230 cm.

This total length is hence computed from the diploid genome but counting only a single chromatid per chromosome. For a haploid genome, the length would be closer to 115 cm and for a diploid genome when counting the sister chromatids, the length would be about 460 cm.

Answer (score 0):

I've have this doubt for the longest time about a chromosome being a monad or diad and when. DNA is always in the form of loose chromatin fibres at all times except during metaphase- when it is condensed onto chromosomes. If you were to condense these chromatic fibres into chromosomes, it would form monads with one sister chromatid only. While during metaphase they form dad's with 2 sister chromatids, twice the dose and thus twice the length of total DNA